# Why my spark streaming demo does not output anything

Tags: spark-streaming

Recently,I am learning the book - learning-spark-o-reilly-2015 . I tried to run the spark streaming example,StreamingLogInput. The code is as follows:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName("StreamingLogInput")
// Create a StreamingContext with a 1 second batch size
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
// Create a DStream from all the input on port 7777
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 7777)
val errorLines = processLines(lines)
// Print out the lines with errors, which causes this DStream to be evaluated
errorLines.print()
// start our streaming context and wait for it to "finish"
ssc.start()

def processLines(lines: DStream[String]) = {
// Filter our DStream for lines with "error"
lines.filter(_.contains("error"))
}
```

When I run this program in the singlenode machine using as follows,

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--class com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.scala.StreamingLogInput \
--master spark://singlenode:7077 \
/home/hadoop/project/learning-spark/target/scala-2.10/learning-spark-examples_2.10-0.0.1.jar \
spark://singlenode:7077
```

and in another window, I type the order

```
nc -l 7777
```

and type some fake logs
but no error log was output.
And the log is as follows:

```
16/11/24 04:20:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1479932447800 in memory 
on singlenode:37112 (size: 32.0 B, free: 267.2 MB)
16/11/24 04:20:49 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932449000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:50 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932450000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:51 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932451000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:51 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1479932451000 in memory on singlenode:37112 (size: 33.0 B, free: 267.2 MB) 
16/11/24 04:20:52 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932452000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:53 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932453000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:54 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932454000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:55 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932455000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:56 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932456000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:57 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932457000 ms
16/11/24 04:20:58 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1479932458000 ms
```

Why did this happen?Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your Configuration on which you are running can you please share your cluster configuration ! here

Comment: I run the program just in my virtual machine and in one machine. And the spark configuration is very simple, the master and worker run in the same machine. I can run other spark program successfully, but cannot run the stream like others. The spark version is 1.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by specifying more than one executor when submit the application, for example local[3].